# Extract phrases in bash (using sed)

Tags: bash, sed, jq

I'm trying to extract some fragments of JSON document using regular expressions in bash. My goal is to catch every instance of this phrase and save them in new file. I thought that sed is good tool for such tasks.

I've tried sth like this:

```
sed '"temp":[0-9]+\.[0-9]*' weather.txt >> newFile.txt
```

Example of weather.txt:

```
{"temp":281.61,"temp_min":280.005,"temp_max":281.61,"pressure":1033.941,"sea_level":1033.941,"grnd_level":1024.038,"humidity":57,"temp_kf":1.6},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.19,"deg":6.817},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2019-04-19 18:00:00"},{"dt":1555707600,"main":{"temp":279.9,"temp_min":278.7,"temp_max":279.9,"pressure":1034.219,"sea_level":1034.219,"grnd_level":1024.211,"humidity":64,"temp_kf":1.2}
```

Expected result for input like this above is: :

```
 "temp":281.61 
 "temp":279.9
```

Despite trying defferent variations it isn't still correct.
Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is for searching and replacing regular expressions in a file/files.
I would normally use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) for parsing JSON but your sample is an invalid JSON value and I assume so is your actual input, so, use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) instead:

```
$ grep -o '"temp":[0-9.]*' weather.txt > newfile.txt
$ cat newfile.txt
"temp":281.61
"temp":279.9
```

Comment: Great answer  --  To *completely* answer, his question, I'd write out to file: `grep -o '"temp":[0-9.]*' weather.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: It is exactly what I was thinking about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try gnu sed

```
 sed -En 's/"temp":\s*[0-9.]+/\n&\n/g; s/[^\n]*(\n("temp":\s*[0-9.]+)|\s*$)/\2/gp' weather.txt >> newFile.txt
```